# Magento Javascript events

Tags: javascript, adminhtml, model, magento2.4.4

How does one discover which Javascript events exist in Magento 2?

I need to run some Javascript code in an adminhtml form for a custom module. The code should run after the fields are displayed (i.e. the spinner disappears). Is there a Javascript event that runs at that time? Or should I just check the existence of the target field with `setInterval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento doesn't provide any specific JS events for full rendered form or specific elements. You can try to play with `contentUpdated`, but i guess better to use `setInterval`

```js
// $ is jQuery
/**
 * @param {string} selector
 * @param {CallableFunction} callback
 * @param {null|$} context
 */
function waitForElement(selector, callback, context) {
    var startTime = Date.now(), checkFrequency = 500, timeout = 10000;
    if (typeof context === 'undefined') {
        context = $('document');
    }
    (function loopSearch() {
        if (context.find(selector).length > 0) {
            callback();
            return;
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (timeout && Date.now() - startTime > timeout) {
                    return;
                }
                loopSearch();
            }, checkFrequency);
        }
    })();
}

// using like
waitForElement(selector, function(){});
waitForElement(selector, function(){}, $(parentSelector));
```

Alternative is using `uiRegistry`

```js
// uiRegistry is uiRegistry
uiRegistry.get('index = field_name', function () {
    // custom logic
});
```

See more examples in doc [uiRegistry](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uiregistry.html)

Also you can use `$.Deferred()` and `$.when(...).then(...)`